# Refresh View lightning app into visualforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom-button, lightning-apps, aura

I need to put a Button in the record Detail View that executes some code through aura componenet.

I've generated a lightning app and put it into a visualforce page that has been set behind the button.

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardcontroller="Lead">
<apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />

<div id="lightning" />

<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:ExposeChangeOwnerVF", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:CambioOwner",
      { label : "",
      recordId : '{!Lead.Id}' },
      "lightning",
      function(cmp) {

      });
    });
</script>
```

Now I want to refresh the page after the component has done the callback:

```
 if(state === "SUCCESS"){
            console.log('step 3');

            $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
```

But when I click the button I get this error:

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined] Callback failed: apex://CambioOwner_Controller/ACTION$changeOwnerForSelectedRecord Failing descriptor

It seems that the problem shows up only when I embed the component into the visualforce through the lightning app, but If I use it as a quick action it work without any errors.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lightning statndard events like $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire(); are not supported when lightning component is used in visual force pages.

Comment: So there is no way to do that? I would like to refresh the detail view after some field update are done!

Comment: Can you please tell me  if what was the need to use the vf page insted of using lightning component directly?

Comment: I don't want to show the modal that it's open while executing a quick action.

Comment: Looks like there is not a direct way but what you can do is creating your own refresh method and re-initializing the variables.

Comment: So far, I've just set the Height of quick action modal to 0% and by using the force:closeQuickAction the user will view the modal only for second! I hope SF will improve this functionality!

Answer (score 0):

In visualforce pages you can use [sforce.one](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm) methods.
So if it suits you you can reload existing page by using sforce.one.navigateToURL(..)

```
 <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!redirectURL!=''}">            
             <script type="text/javascript">
                  sforce.one.navigateToURL('{!redirectURL}');                  
            </script>
  </apex:outputPanel>
```